# Calculate function in two different part

Tags: r

I have a vector `y`, which is a series of positive integers. For each value in `y`, I want to calculate:

- `z <- 1/y`,
- but for elements that `y` is 1 I need to set `z` is zero.
- Finally I need a vector of `z` with zero for `y` is 1 and `1/y` for `y` is not 1.

How can I do that?

Comment: Sorry my question was too simplified. Say, y is a matrix with integers.calculate z<-1/y, and set z zero if y is zero. I tried to use ifelse, but got error: NaNs produced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very easy to do this with logical indexing:

```
z <- 1/y  # will have some Inf values but not throw an error
z[y==0] <- 0   # changes the Inf's to 0
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `ifelse` and do it in one step:

```
y <- 1:5
z <- ifelse(y==1, 0, 1/y)

cbind(y, z)
     y         z
[1,] 1 0.0000000
[2,] 2 0.5000000
[3,] 3 0.3333333
[4,] 4 0.2500000
[5,] 5 0.2000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending what Andrie has said to a matrix...

```
y <- matrix(1:25, ncol=5) # define the matrix y
z <- matrix(ifelse(y==1, 0, 1/y), ncol=ncol(y))
```

or I could just say

```
z <- matrix(ifelse(y==1, 0, 1/y), ncol=5)
```